# How to display single/particular data record from database -django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I want to display a particular data record from the database of a person who is logged in to the website. I have a default primary key in the migration. Other than that I don't have any of the primary or foreign keys. Below is the models.py and template codes.

---

**models.py**

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    Email = models.CharField(max_length=40)
   to = models.CharField(max_length=40)
   cc = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   subject = models.CharField(max_length=25)
   
   class Meta:
        db_table = 'ticket'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Email
```

---

Following is the views which I had used before, that display's the whole data from the database.

**Views.py**

```
def ticket(request):
  ticket = Ticket.objects.all()
  return render(request, 'web/ticket.html', {'ticket':ticket})
```

But I want to display data of the respective mail id

---

**ticket.html**

```
{% for ticket in ticket %}
<fieldset id="first">
    <label for="From"><b>From</b></label> &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;
     <input type="text" id="From" name="From" style="width:100%" value="{{ ticket.Email }}" required> <br> <br>

     <label for="To"><b>To</b></label> &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;
     <input type="text" id="To" name="To" style="width:100%" value="{{ ticket.to }}" required><br> <br>

    <label for="Cc"><b>Cc</b></label> &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;
    <input type="text" id="Cc" name="Cc" style="width:100%"  value="{{ ticket.cc }}" required><br> <br>

    <label for="Subject"><b>Subject</b></label> &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <input type="text" id="Subject" name="Subject" style="width:100%" value="{{ ticket.subject }}" required><br> <br>
 </fieldset>
{% endfor %}
```

---

Thanking you in advance. You will be highly appreciated if you could explain the needful code.

Comment: You could filter on `Ticket` in the view using request object - `ticket = Ticket.objects.filter(Email=request.user.email)`

Comment: [filtering objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters), [getting unique object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get)

Comment: @Conans Sir got a blank page instead of data display.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat okay sir. will try this.